# Let $\det(A)\ne0$ and $\det(A+E)\ne0$. Can we say that, no eigenvalue of pencil $A+tE$ can be equal $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,E\in M_n$ and $t\in[0,1]$

and $\det(A)\ne0$ and $\det(A+E)\ne0$.

Can we say that, no eigenvalue of pencil $A+tE$ can be equal $1$?(for all $t\in[0,1]$)

Comment: Is $E$ the identity matrix or any matrix?

Comment: @AnuragA - Any matrix

Comment: @H.S what if $A = I,$ and $E$ is a matrix with all zero entries?

Comment: You can say that no eigenvalue of the pencil $(A,E)$ is $-1$.

Comment: Is no one else confused by the term "pencil"?

Comment: The eigenvalues of the pencil $(A,B)$ are all $t$ such that $\det (A-tB) = 0$.

Comment: ambiguous question. Is the tested claim "there exist no A,E so that det(A+tE)=1 for all t" ?

Comment: The question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @copper.hat - Why?

Comment: What pencil are you referring to in the question. $A+tE$ is a matrix, not a pencil.

Comment: @GitGud certainly not. I had a nice chuckle at it since it's an odd word choice.

Comment: I'm just dying to find the missing pencil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. As the comments and the other answer here show, there is an unfortunate misunderstanding here.

*The eigenvalues of a [matrix pencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil)* $(A,B)$ (or $A+tB$ if one is sloppy) actually refers not to the eigenvalues of the *matrix* $A+tB$, but the set of all complex numbers $t$ such that $\det(A+tB)=0$ (or, in an alternative definition, those $t$s such that $\det(A-tB)=0$). Confusing or misleading as it is, the term is unfortunately a standard one in linear algebra literature.

In the OP's case, since the given conditions state that both $\det(A+0E)$ and $\det(A+1E)$ are nonzero, the numbers $0$ and $1$ are, by definition, not the eigenvalues of the *matrix pencil* $(A,E)$.

Comment: Thank you.            ...         .

Comment: Well I'll be. Those are some really unfortunate terms to use.

Answer (score 1):

Without further conditions, I do not think you can say anything along these lines, even if you restrict to the open interval $(0,1)$. It is easy to imagine that $0$ and $1$ might somehow be "edge" cases, but they aren't. Consider $A = \frac{5}{4}I$ and $E=-\frac{1}{2}I$, then for all $t$, $A + tE = (\frac{5}{4}-\frac{t}{2})I$. Picking $t = \frac{1}{2}$, we get $A+tE = I$ which obviously has an eigenvalue of $1$.

Comment: Thank you, but, please see this paper, page  323 - Lemma 11 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWl8rPlJzLAhUrG5oKHa5-AxQQFgg5MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmcom%2F2008-77-261%2FS0025-5718-07-02005-4%2FS0025-5718-07-02005-4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFflq5-Tqf4qWR3tJ54QyIkdHppWA&bvm=bv.115339255,d.bGs

Comment: I didn't read the full paper, just that lemma but there must be a major subtlety that is being overlooked here, as my example shows.